# How to place every node of a content type under a menu item?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm looking for a module that will let me add every node of a content type as a link with a common parent link.

Comment: For D6 https://drupal.org/project/node_menu_parent

Comment: Check this http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.ae/2009/03/create-menu-link-to-particular-node.html

Comment: OP is talking about D7 , Core Menu settings with Default menu link module solves above problem :-)

Comment: @AnilSagar I know he is talking about D7, that's why I mentioned D6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Default Menu Link](https://drupal.org/project/default_menu_link) module for this and core menu settings for content type..

> Provides the user with a check box on all content types to set the
>   "provide a menu link" value to true by default.
>
> This is basically a nice way to ensure the menu system is adhered to
>   by all content authors.

You need to set Menu settings for content type..

[image]

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm worried whether I have to give the user permissions to change menus (I don't want to) and, worse, actually display the menu widget (form is already crowded).